# Disable bypass for Windows 10 log in?

Tags: windows-10, bypass

I have suspicion to believe that my Windows 10 computer is being tampered with when I'm away.  I only have one account, which is administrative. When I return to it, the time displayed is off, which lead me to believe that someone messed with it.  I checked the event viewer, and it seemed like the proposed hacker, who had physical access to my computer, was utilizing NT Authority and logging in with an Administrative account.  Another notable event was LSASS.exe starts and the auditing subsystem is initialized. At the end, my files I have stored had been compromised. How exactly did he/she get access into my computer, and how can I stop it from happening again?

Answer (score -1):

> How exactly did he/she get access into my computer, and how can I stop it from happening again?

If anyone in the world would know answer to that... there would be no cyber-crimes. :)

You say that you see successful login in system events. You can check which kind of login it was ([check this](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624) - "logon type").

You should start with changing your password. Use something strong - letters, numbers and special signs, quite long and not containing any words. Something like 'se!&^p222sui78$@'. This will prevent quick brute-force and you will learn if someones got your password or is gaining access otherwise.